# Update data on a website

Tags: pi-2, web-server, node.js, web-interface

I'm trying to build a dashboard which will be hosted and updated at regular intervals by a Raspberry Pi.

The Raspberry should ping various devices of an IP surveillance system on his same network to check that all cameras and nvr are online and working. 
The website needs to be updated according to these values.

I have no problem building the front-end interface and the scripting side on the Raspberry but I really don't know how to make the two "talk" together.

Doing some research I've found out that WebSocket and Ajax could be a solution for my problem but I don't know which is better for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

They don't necessarily need to talk directly to each other. A Polling program could periodically ping each device and update a database with the status of each device, and a server-side program written in something  like node.js or Python could query the database and build the web pages. They don't even have to be on the same server.

I'd suggest looking in to some of the existing network management solutions such as Nagios as a starter.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Nagios which requires no coding and minimal setup.